# How to implement proper exception handling in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

How to implement proper exception handling in Spring MVC

Comment: Why Don't you ask your client what they meant? We are no more able to read their minds than you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need exception handling in your controllers just to log your exceptions because you already implemented some `@ExceptionHandler`s. You can log directly there using a proper logging API and implementation (like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)), not with System.out.

I am also assuming that you are not passing any stack trace information to your `ErrorResponse` class because I see only references to error code and exception message during the initialization of an instance.

To include stack trace information you could implement an additional `String` field in your `ErrorResponse` class, that you can initialize with [commons-lang getStackTrace](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable)).

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace should not be printed with the printStackTrace method, since it is using System.out.println() to print the message. You should instead print the exception message and its stacktrace with a logger, such as Log4j.

Initiate logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Clazz.class);
```

Upon exception:

```
logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
```